# Why am I being asked to create a pipeline when deploying a github file to Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku, owasp

Need help deploying an app after deploying github file into Heroku. I'm new to creating an app and or pipeline on Heroku.
github webpage: https://github.com/juice-shop/juice-shop/blob/master/README.md#heroku
[Creator's window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivORq.png)
[Personal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6zhn.png)

From the Github webpage, I was expecting to see 'deploy app' after creating a new app name and deploying the README.md folder into hiroku. Unfortunately, I was asked to create a new pipeline or create an app.